# ListView download Images

Tags: android

sorry, but i can't find the other question and i can't login with my facebook account, so i have to ask again :)

I have a listview with a text and an imageView. For each entry i have a different picture, which have to download from my server. 
My listview shows 2 entrys at the same time. If i'm scrolling down, the entrys will get the pictures of my first entry, but they have another url.
Here is my getView:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if(rowResourceId!=R.layout.search_empty_list) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflator.inflate(rowResourceId, null);
                final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                viewHolder.imgPic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgPic);         

                if (viewHolder.imgPic != null) {
                    String strUrl = mainUrl+list.get(position).getUrl();
                    new ImageDownload(viewHolder.imgPic).execute(strUrl);
                }

                view.setTag(viewHolder);

            } else {
                view = convertView;
            }
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

            holder.textName.setText(list.get(position).getName());


        } else {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);

            TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView1.setText(list.get(0).getName());
        }
        return view;

    }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView ImageView load same pictures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202269/listview-imageview-load-same-pictures)

Comment: YEES, thanks :D.. I didn't find that ;D

Answer (score 0):

You are setting image only once when creating view.
It should be like this:

```
ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
holder.textName.setText(list.get(position).getName());
String strUrl = mainUrl+list.get(position).getUrl();
new ImageDownload(holder.imgPic).execute(strUrl);
```